# Multiprocessing "Pool" hangs on running program

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have written a program to use the "Pool" from multiprocessing python package,but it keeps hanging the kernel.(I am using Jupyter with Anaconda,by the way)

I tried using a function from an imported package like "math",which works perfectly,but, the moment i use a function i created in the same python file it doesn't work.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(x):
   for i in x:
      return i+1

ar=[1,2,3,4,5]
def main():
    pool=mp.Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(f,ar)
if __name__== '__main__':
    main()
```

It shows that the kernel is working,but the cpu usage sits at 0%.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Your code raises `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `ar` is not within the local scope of your main function, it's above it.  Put it inside and it should work.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x+1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ar=[1,2,3,4,5]
    with Pool(4) as p:
        print(p.map(f, ar))
```

Also consider `map` is taking your iterable and assigning it across the processes, in essence it is doing the `for` loop for you.  Therefore you can access the x directly.

And then last, using `with` as a context manager ensures your Pool closes when it is complete. [[docs]](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool)

**Edit:** I edited and tested the above code and mine sends the correct values and closes properly.

This code also works for me in both Spyder 3.2.6 and standard terminal.  Both snippets close out properly and don't hang on my machine.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(x):
    return x+1

def main():
    ar = [1,2,3,4,5]
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
    print(pool.map(f, ar))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: No,still the same thing.

Comment: Still,the same problem.

Comment: The location of `ar` is a red herring. This code is essentially the same as the python documentation for `multiprocessing`. The location of the fault must be in the environment under which python is being run. I get both reported symptoms: Works and Doesn't Work depending on which IDE I use. I haven't yet worked out why this is.

Comment: Running the code as above from terminal `python test.py` I get no issues.  Many IDEs have issues running multiprocessing code so that could be part of it for sure.

Comment: I have tested it on the spyder IDE and Jupyter,but it dosent work,but it works on IDLE.I don't know why.What IDE are you using?

Comment: But,whenever i use IDLE with pool,the malwarebytes anitvirus service kicks in to max,using 100% of my cpu.

Comment: I tested it in Spyder 3.2.6 with Python 3.6 and it works fine.  I also tested code closer to yours and it works fine as well.

Comment: I added a second snippet that I tested that is yours with `ar` moved and `def f(x)` corrected.  I tested in Spyder and outside of it and both worked for me.

Comment: Doesn't Spyder have Ipython instead of python?